# Macro quote the expanded result

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have a macro like this

```
#define REQUIRE(condition,message) \
  if (!(condition)) { \
    std::ostringstream _msg_stream; \
    _msg_stream << __FILE__ <<" at line: " << __LINE__ << " becasue " << message << std::endl; \
    throw Error(_msg_stream.str());\
  } else

#define QUOTEME_(x) #x
#define QUOTEME(x) QUOTEME_(x)

#define JSON_SPIRIT_SAFE_LOOKUP(__type) \
  if(iter != obj.end()){\
    if(iter->second.type() == json_spirit::##__type##_type) { \
  return iter->second.get_##__type##(); \
}else{\
  std::cerr << "JsonDump: "<<obj << std::endl;\
  REQUIRE(false, " The value type is not of type " << QUOTEME(__type) <<\
                   " with key: " << key << std::endl);\
}\
  }else{\
std::cerr << "JsonDump: "<<obj << std::endl;\
REQUIRE(false, " Cannot look up by the key: " << key<<std::endl);\
```

}

and when I invoke it with

```
JSON_SPIRIT_SAFE_LOOKUP(str);
```

I get

```
ID: 6172: ..\phx\jsonutililty.cpp at line: 107 becasue  The value type is not of type __type with key: blah
```

where `__type` is not expanded. Anyone know how to expand it?

Comment: Interesting -- what compiler are you using?  When I run your code through gcc -E it gets expanded correctly: ...`<< " becasue " << " The value type is not of type " << "str" << " with key: " << key`..., including the misspelled `becasue`.  You do get warnings about the invalid `::##` and `##()` however.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a two-stage macro for concatenation, for example.

```
#define CONCAT_(x, y) x ## y
#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCAT_(x, y)

if (iter->second.type() == CONCAT(CONCAT(json_spirit::, __type), _type)
```

Comment: won't make any difference in this case -- you only need to use this if `str` is a macro you want expanded -- AND your example will still give the error about incorrectly trying to paste `::` and `str` which can't form a single token